# Converting span{[1,1,1][2,-1,1][5,-7,1]} in R3 into a scalar equation. My answer different than the teacher's. Not sure where I went wrong.

Tags: matrices, geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

We have three vectors, **v1 = (1,1,1), v2 = (2,-1,1), v3=(5,-7,1).**

Together, these vectors form a plane in R3. For my (not-for-marks) homework question, I'm tasked with converting this to a scalar equation. However, my answer differs from that of the teachers. I'm not sure why.

Here is my answer: **2x+3y+6z = 0** (wrong)

Here is the teacher's: **2x+y-3z=0** (correct? I assume the teacher is right?)

To get my answer, I did this:

- Added the 3 spanning vectors to a 3x3 matrix
- Converted the matrix to RREF form
- Noticed 1 of the vectors is dependent
- Created the vector equation for the span: **x=t[3,-4,1]**
- Converted the vector equation to the parametric equation: **x=3t, y=-4t, z=t**
- Wrote each of the **x,y,z** in terms of **t** and substituted them together to get **2x+3y+6z = 0**, which is wrong based on my teacher's answer.

Can anybody explain where I went wrong? Thanks so much!

Comment: Just by substituting your $x$, $y$, and $z$ values, you can see right away that there's an issue with your solution because none of the three vectors is in your plane.

Comment: @Kman3 That's why I'm confused. I'm not sure where I went wrong along the way. I solved the problem 3 times, and got the same answer each time.

Comment: as it happens, an answer can be found by row reducing the 3 by 3 matrix, putting each of three vectors as a row

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the math in your question. You'll find that your question will be better received and increase your chance of getting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you find that $v_3$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, you know that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the two independent vectors inside your plane. Then you can just take the cross product of $v_1$ and $v_2$, and its coordinates are the coefficients of the teacher's equation:

$$v_1 \times v_2=(2,1,-3)$$
$$\implies 2x+y-3z=0$$

Comment: That works, however, we aren't permitted to use cross product. Is there another way?

Comment: almost. $2x+y-3z$

Comment: @MatthewTrent   write out the 3 by 3 matrix and row reduce. Do you know how to row reduce a matrix?

Comment: @WillJagy Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @WillJagy I row reduced the matrix down to RREF form (with these as the columns from left to right, not sure how to format it here): (1,0,0)(0,1,0)(-3,4,0). You said I can somehow use this to find the coefficients of the teacher's answer?

Answer (score 0):

We ought to be a little careful with this. I claim that the (column)  null  vector of
$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&1&1 \\
2&-1&1 \\
5&-7&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

gives the correct coefficients $A,B,C $   for your plane being $Ax+By+Cz=0$

I also claim that the same (nonzero) null vector is a null vector for the row-reduced matrix. It would be really nice to see your row reduced version of the $M.$   perhaps you could type in three rows in order,   just nine numbers as a comment

The result should have two nonzero rows  followed by a zero row. Each nonzero row has more than one nonzero entry

Here is the fully reduced  version gotten by the most straightforward method

$$
M_R =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&\frac{2}{3} \\
0&1&\frac{1}{3} \\
0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

What is the (nonzero) null  vector required to be? I tokk $C = -3$  for convenience

Comment: Here is my row reduced version: (1,0,0)(2,-3,0)(5,-12,0). I'm still unsure how this REF version of my original matrix solves my question and converts it into a scalar equation.

Comment: @MatthewTrent  please find a null vector of my matrix I called $M_R$  I agree that you don't yet know how that answers your original question, but it does; if you can find the null vector correctly you should begin to see that.

Comment: I'm unsure what a null vector is, we haven't been taught that yet, or at least not by that name.

Comment: @MatthewTrent   with my coefficients $A,B,C$  it is just a vector that solves both $A + \frac{2}{3} C = 0$   and  $B + \frac{1}{3} C = 0.$   That is why it is convenient to choose $C = -3 $